# Imaginary Frequency in Bosonic Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian, bosons

I'm doing some calculations for my Thesis involving a Bosonic Hamiltonian of the form:

\begin{equation}
H=\sum_{\vec{k}}\alpha\ a^{+}_{\vec{k}}a^{+}_{-\vec{k}} + \beta\  a^{+}_{\vec{k}}a^{-}_{\vec{k}} +\gamma\  a^{-}_{\vec{k}}a^{+}_{\vec{k}}  + \delta\  a^{-}_{\vec{k}}a^{-}_{-\vec{k}}
\end{equation}

where $a^{\pm}$ are creation and annihilation operators and the Greek letters are just real coefficients that may be functions of $\vec{k}$. This Hamiltonian is hermitian only if $\alpha=\delta$. After diagonalizing this using a Bogoliuvov transformation

\begin{align*}
b^{\pm}_{\vec{k}} = \cosh(\phi)\ a^{\pm}_{\vec{k}}-\sinh(\phi)\ a^{\mp}_{-\vec{k}}
\end{align*}

One obtains the usual result

\begin{equation}
H=E_0+\sum_{\vec{k}}\omega(\vec{k})b^+_{{\vec{k}}}b^-_{\vec{k}}=E_0+ \sum_{\vec{k}}\omega(\vec{k})\ \hat{n}_{\vec{k}}
\end{equation}

Where $E_0$ is a constant that doesn't matter at all and $\omega(\vec{k})$ is

\begin{equation}
\omega(\vec{k})=(\beta+\gamma)\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{2\alpha}{\beta +\gamma}\right)^2}
\end{equation}

It is quite obvious that when $\frac{\beta+\gamma}{2}<\alpha$ the frequency becomes imaginary. This condition, back in the Hamiltonian, means that the non-diagonal terms weight more than the diagonal ones. This is because the condition for the angle $\phi$ to diagonalize $H$ is $\tanh (2\phi) = \frac{2 \alpha}{\beta + \gamma}$. This means that when $2\alpha>\beta + \gamma$ we can't perform the Bogoliubov transformation (This is why the frequency was imaginary). So the question remains:

**How do I diagnalize $H$ when $2\alpha>\beta + \gamma$?**

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that if $\alpha$ is infinitely large then your Hamiltonian is not Hermitian and you'll get imaginary eigenvalues because of that.

Comment: please clarify the statement: “Hamiltonian can _only_ be diagonalized if $\alpha = \delta$ because it has to conserve the number of particles.” 
I think diagonalization of the Hamiltonian is always possible, even when $\alpha \neq \delta$.

Comment: Could you provide the original Hamiltonian on which you performed the Holstein-Primakoff transformation? Add a few important steps which lead to the current Hamiltonian in your post.
Could you please also give the value of $E_0$?

Comment: Another point is that the Hamiltonian in your post is generally **particle-nonconserving** due to the presence of $ a^{+}_k \, a^{+}_{-k} $ and $ a^{-}_k \, a^{-}_{-k} $ terms. In other words, when either $ \alpha \neq 0 $ or $ \delta \neq 0 $, the $a$-particle number operator $ \hat{n}_q^a = a_q^+ a_q^- $ does _not_ commute with your Hamiltonian, afais.
Have you checked the commutator $ [ \hat{n}_q^a , H ] $?

Comment: There could be a way to interpret the imaginary eigenvalues, but one needs further details of the derivation, from the first spin-Hamiltonian up the current one.

Comment: re. the edit: $\tanh\to\tan$?

Comment: the condition for diagonalization in the Bogoliubov transformation is tanh(2\phi)= 2\alpha / (\beta + \gamma).

Comment: I do not understand your formula. If you insert the expression of $b$ into your third formula you only find the conditions $\beta = \omega(k) \cosh^2 \phi$ and  $\gamma = \omega(k) \sinh^2 \phi$ and $\omega(k) \cosh \phi \sinh\phi = -\alpha = -\delta$. Since $\cosh^2 \phi - \sinh^2 \phi =1$, the first two conditions produces $\omega(k)= \beta -\gamma$.

Comment: Next, the further condition produces $\sinh 2\phi = -\frac{\alpha}{2(\beta-\gamma)}$ which is always solvable for $\beta \neq \gamma$. The only constraint seems to be $\beta \geq \gamma$ otherwise $\omega(k) <0$. (I assumed also $\omega(k)= \omega(-k)$.)

Comment: Maybe are $a_k$ and $a_{-k}$  defined for $k$ ranging in the same set? So they are two **different** types of ladder operators (?)

Comment: @ValterMoretti I think you made a mistake somewhere. One should get $\beta + \gamma =\omega(\vec{k}) (\cosh^2 \phi + \sinh^2\phi) = \omega(\vec{k})\cosh 2\phi$ and $\alpha = \delta = -\omega(\vec{k})\cosh\phi\sinh\phi = -\omega(\vec{k})\sinh 2\phi / 2$. It may be that there is a sign error in OP's 3rd equation, but otherwise it (as well as the resulting spectrum) looks fine.

Comment: $b_k^+b_k^- = (c a_k^+- s a_{-k}^-)(c a_k^-- s a_{-k}^+) = c^2a_k^+a_k^- + s^2a_{-k}^-a_{-k}^+ -sc( a_{-k}^-a_k^-+ a_k^+  a_{-k}^+)$

Comment: @higgsss So, comparing with the intial expression of the Hamiltonian,  $\beta= \omega(k) \cosh^2\phi$, and **if $\omega(k)=\omega(-k)$**, also $\gamma = \omega(k)\sinh^2\phi $. So $\beta/\omega - \gamma/\omega = 1$. Where is my mistake? Perhaps $\omega(k) \neq\omega(-k)$?

Comment: Now I see, it is in fact supposed that $\omega(k)=\omega(-k)$, The trouble is that I did not use commutation relations! $s^2a^-_ka^+_k = s^2a^+_ka^-_k + s^2$...so collecting all identical terms I find both $E_0$ and the relation you pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diagonalization is not meaningful if $2\alpha > \beta + \gamma$ because the Hamiltonian becomes unphysical (unbounded below) in this case.

To see this, let's consider a simpler Hamiltonian:
\begin{equation}
H = 2A\, a^+ a^- + B\, (a^+ a^+ + a^- a^-),
\end{equation}
where the canonical commutation relation $[a^-, a^+] = 1$ holds. Next, let's construct the "position" and "momentum" operators as
\begin{equation}
x = \frac{a^+ - a^-}{\sqrt{2}},\quad p = \frac{i(a^+ - a^-)}{\sqrt{2}}.
\end{equation}
(Note that $[x,p] = i$ is satisfied.) Inverting the above relations gives
\begin{equation}
a^\mp = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (x \pm ip).
\end{equation}

Then, the Hamiltonian can be written as
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
H &= A\, (x^2 + p^2 - 1) + B\,(x^2 - p^2)\\
&=(A+B)\,x^2 + (A-B)\,p^2 - A.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
One should have $A \ge 0$ and $-A \le B \le A$ for the above Hamiltonian to be bounded below.

To perform the same analysis on the particular Hamiltonian OP considered, let's define a new set of ladder operators $c_{\vec{k}}^\pm$ and $d_{\vec{k}}^\pm$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&a_{\vec{k}}^\pm = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (c_{\vec{k}}^\pm + d_{\vec{k}}^\pm),\\
&a_{-\vec{k}}^\pm = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (c_{\vec{k}}^\pm - d_{\vec{k}}^\pm).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Then, OP's Hamiltonian can be represented as a sum over unordered pairs $\{\vec{k},-\vec{k}\}$ of the following:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
H_{\vec{k}} &= \alpha\, c_{\vec{k}}^+c_{\vec{k}}^+ + \beta\, c_{\vec{k}}^+c_{\vec{k}}^- + \gamma\, c_{\vec{k}}^-c_{\vec{k}}^+ + \delta\, c_{\vec{k}}^-c_{\vec{k}}^- + (c \rightarrow d),\\
&= \alpha\, (c_{\vec{k}}^+c_{\vec{k}}^+ + c_{\vec{k}}^-c_{\vec{k}}^-) + (\beta+\gamma)\, c_{\vec{k}}^+c_{\vec{k}}^- + (c \rightarrow d) + 2\gamma
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $(c\rightarrow d)$ denotes the terms obtained by replacing $c_{\vec{k}}^\pm$ by $d_{\vec{k}}^\pm$. Identifying $\alpha = B$ and $\beta + \gamma = 2A$, one can see that the Hamiltonian becomes unbounded below if $2\alpha > \beta + \gamma$.

Comment: I guess the OP's derivation via Holstein-Primakoff trafo. on a _ferromagnetic_ Hamiltonian (not provided) has some flaws. The approximation has been so drastic that the Hamiltonian is no more Hermitian for some values of $\alpha$ and $\gamma$. This is certainly problematic and leads to unphysical results.

Comment: I do not understand well your conditions: How you distinguish between $\vec{k}$ and $-\vec{k}$? Otherwise the double definition of $a^\pm_{\vec{k}}$ does not make sense.

Comment: Perhaps I understand, you are supposing to separate the set of vectors $\vec{k}$ into two parts. In fact then you suppose that there are two notions of ladder operators $c$ and $d$, whereas you initially had only one kind of them $a$. However, reading the original question, it does not seem to me that the OP uses the same convention (though it would make sense as you both get similar conditions).

Comment: Great Answer! I'm about to give you the bounty. I still have a question though. Altough this Hamiltonian is unbounded below, it is still hermitian so it should have a diagonalized form, doesn't it? I would really appreciate any comments on this issue. Thanks!

(Just asking if you don't know the answer I'd obviusly still give you the bounty)

Comment: @ValterMoretti I've just defined $c_{\vec{k}}^{\pm}$ and $d_{\vec{k}}^{\pm}$ as linear combinations of $a_{\vec{k}}^{\pm}$ and $a_{-\vec{k}}^{\pm}$ Then, except for $\vec{k} = 0$, there is redundancy because $c_{\vec{k}}^{\pm} = c_{-\vec{k}}^{\pm}$ and $d_{\vec{k}}^{\pm}= -d_{-\vec{k}}^{\pm}$, and that is why we take the sum of $H_{\vec{k}}$ over unordered pairs $\{\vec{k}, -\vec{k}\}$.

Comment: @P.C.Spaniel Because $p^2-x^2$ is the operator relevant for the case $2\alpha > \beta + \gamma$, you could search the keyword "inverted harmonic oscillator".